# exceptions.AttributeError: class KeyAgent has no attribute 'delele_customer_node()'

Tags: python

I've 2 files: customer.py & agent.py. It looks like this:

customer.py:

```
from agent import KeyAgent

class CustomerController(object):

    def __init__(self, container):                                          
        self.key =  container.agent
    def delete(self, path):
       KeyAgent.delele_customer_node()
```

agent.py:

```
class KeyAgent(service.Service):    

    def __init__(self):                              
        pass
    def delele_customer_node():
     ....
```

Python is throwing this exception while running:

```
exceptions.AttributeError: class KeyAgent has no attribute 'delele_customer_node()'
```

Even though I've imported KeyAgent class from agent.py why method `delele_customer_node()` is not accessible from delete() of customer.py?

Comment: because `delete_customer_note` is an instance method, not a class method. The way you have defined it, the method should only be called on an instance of `KeyAgent` object

Answer (score 1):

You must have misspelled the method name (dele**l**e? or dele**t**e?). The KeyAgent class **does** have a method `delete_customer_node` (I will assume that was a typo).

```
>>> class KeyAgent(object):
...   def delete_customer():
...     pass
... 
>>> KeyAgent.delete_customer
<unbound method KeyAgent.delete_customer>
```

That means, the method is there. However your code is quite broken. Unless you use the `staticmethod` or `classmethod` decorators, the first argument of a method "must be" `self`, and you need to instantiate the class to call it. See what happens if you try to call this method directly:

```
>>> KeyAgent.delete_customer()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method delete_customer() must be called with KeyAgent instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```